# Stretch part of object in Autocad or 123D Design

Tags: 3d-printing, autocad

I'm quite new to using 3D Drawing programs, except a bit of work in Google's Sketchup.
As I'm trying to draw a model that should be 3D printed, and heared that Sketchup is kinda bad practice for this, I started using a different program.

I've started drawing in 123D Design, this was quite working, only now I ran into a problem. I've made a mistake, as the right border is to small, and I need to stretch this. This should be quite easy if the corners weren't rounded. But I cannot find any way to stretch this border with 3mm while the corner is rounded.

The same has to be done for the rear plate.

As I couldn't find out how to do this in 123D Design, I've also tried doing it with Autocad. In here, I found the Stretch command, but this doesn't seem to do what I wish to do.

The selected part in the image is the part i want to stretch by 3mm to the right.
[image: Stretched selection]

Sorry for the probably little simple question, but I couldn't find how to do this by myself.

Comment: Can you do it on the command line by changing the value of a dimension?